# How can I use React lazy to Router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, lazy-evaluation

I want to pass the props from router to component

```
function TestComponent({myProps: string}): {
  console.log(myProps)
  useEffect(...)
  return (
    <>...</>  
  )
};
```

My router use react lazy like this

```
import React, { lazy } from 'react';
export const routes = [
  ...
  {
    path: '/test/testComponent',
    exact: true,
    component: lazy(
      () => import('pages/test/TestComponent/index'),
    ),
  },
  ...
];
```

I find this way

```
{
  path: '/test/testComponent',
  component(): React.ReactElement {
  return <DeviceAssignmentLog myProps=''hello />;
  },
},
```

but I have to use lazy with that

how can I solve...

Comment: It *looks* like you are using an older version of `react-router`. Can you confirm the version you are using and edit the post to also include a [mcve] for how you are using this `routes` array?

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the lazy loaded component to a variable and then pass the required props into the config object
so the inside the router file you do something like this

```
import React, { lazy } from 'react';

const LazyLoadedComponent = lazy(()=> import('/path-to-component'))

const routes = [
  ...
  {
    path: '/test/testComponent',
    component:()=>(<LazyLoadedComponent myProps='required-prop-value'  />),
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: throwing `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = lazy(() => import('./pages/Home'))

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Suspense>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home myProps={'hello'} />} />
          // Your routes more here
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```